Unknown permissions on new Samsung?
I have several unknown permissions on my Galaxy S24 Ultra but can start with this one: Under System UI (Android, not Samsung UI 6.1), other app capabilities, com.samsung.android.permission.RETURN_REMOTE_USER_INPUT_VOICE. I cannot change any permissions under this application. States: device requires this permission to operate.

Welcome. As a Q&A site, Stack Exchange prefers to have focused questions, meaning 1 post per question (multiple closely related issues are still acceptable). This post has 2 unrelated questions, 1) unknown permissions, and 2) user-release key build. I removed the 2nd question to conform with the policy. You can still post the 2nd question as a new question. Thank you for your understanding.
